# Orderby string with another character first

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Lets say i got this list:

```
List<string> somelist = new List<string>();
somelist.Add("a");
somelist.Add("b");
somelist.Add("b");
somelist.Add("a*");
somelist.Add("b");
somelist.Add("a*");
somelist.Add("a");
```

Then order it:

```
somelist = somelist.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

When im using OrderBy i gets ordered like this:

```
a
a
a*
a*
b
b
b
```

But I wan't the a with the "*" to be first.
How can i do it?

Comment: What if you have a `b*`?

Comment: I won't have a b*,  the value are predictable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
somelist = somelist
        .OrderBy(x => x.TrimEnd('*'))           // remove * to keep alphabetical order
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.EndsWith("*")) // bool(true=1, false=0), ends with * first
        .ToList();
```

Presuming that not only `a*` but also (if possible) `b*` should come first.

This keeps natural order, so if there is a `"b*"` it will belong to the `"b"`-group. If you instead want  all which ends with `*` at the beginning regardless of the initial letters:

```
somelist = somelist
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.EndsWith("*")) 
        .ThenBy(x => x)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can "order" by all symbols not only "*"

```
List<string> somelist = new List<string>();

......  // INIT VALUES

var ordered = somelist .Sort((x, y) =>
{
    if(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x[0])){
        if(!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y[0])){
            // x is a letter/digit and y is not, override regular CompareTo
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y[0]))
    {
        // y is a letter/digit and x is not, override regular CompareTo
        return 1;
    }
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}).ToList();
```